# Cassandra new nodes not adding to cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I wanna add 2 separate cluster into one cluster. One cluster have data and another one is empty new cluster. 
Even I add all old nodes as seed for new cluster nodes, both cluster not joining. Cassandra version is 2.0.10

I got below log.

```
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/1.2.3.4] 2018-09-24 20:07:03,447 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 386) Handshaking version with /1.2.3.4
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/1.2.3.5] 2018-09-24 20:07:04,449 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 386) Handshaking version with /1.2.3.5
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/1.2.3.6] 2018-09-24 20:07:07,451 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 386) Handshaking version with /1.2.3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge two existing clusters with each other.

You will need to remove all data from all machines in the empty cluster and join them to the existing cluster one by one as you would do normally when scaling up. From what you write it seems you have two seperate clusters with the logical seperator being [cluster_name](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml#L10) configuration value. You need to makes sure this value is the name of the existing cluster.

Comment: I have adding new empty nodes. But those are not identify new cluster. Don't you thing that log part which I add say something about it

Comment: The log message just tells you what nodes are communicating. As you didn't provide any information whether those are new or old nodes it's hard for me to troubleshoot. Did you check your configuration on all nodes so they have the same cluster_name?